# Selecting a table row for highlighting when there are interactive cells

Tags: interaction-design, web-app, tables

I have table that looks like this:
[image]

I need the switches to be toggleable and the *APRAKSTS* to be editable (it probably needs some kind of indicator). Also, as you can see, the last 3 columns have highlighted all matching cell values for the highlighted 4th row.

My question is - how do I select the highlighted row? In my opinion, it's not enough to just let the user click on any non-interactive row element. I think it needs some kind of selector, e.g., a radio button (which will probably look ugly). Also, how do I highlight the selected row better? I think the bold text is not visible enough.

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting a row should be as simple as a style change to the whole row whenever it is hovered, which should not have to interfere with the interactions (perhaps a single row-length rectangle of 15% opacity over the whole thing, coded so it does not interfere with interaction):

[image: Updated table image]

As for a row selector, checkboxes to the left of table rows are a common element that can provide row selection (the image above kind of combines both the hover and a selected row). This does, however, open the possibility of multiple selects and a need for bulk actions - I am guessing that you do NOT want to have multiple selections? If that's the case then yes, something more like a radio button (or some exclusive select control) might be more appropriate; you could style it to be less ugly, of course, but it should still broadcast that it is a single-selection control.

Do rows actually NEED to be selected, or was that just an avenue for highlighting them? Providing selection tools has all sorts of other implied ramifications (are there new controls available for the selected item? What is the reason for making the selection? Is multi-select an option, and how do the controls differ if so?). If selection is only an avenue to highlighting, I expect coding it so that each table row is a hover area and providing highlighting for the row on hover would be your best bet.